# Transferring variables between python and python or shell scripts

Tags: python, bash, shell, global-variables

From a main python script, here `main.py`, I would like to call multiple subscripts, which are either python scripts themselves (here `sub1.py` for simplicity) or bash/shell scripts (here `sub2.sh` for simplicity; these are called via `subprocess.Popen()`). The subscripts need several variables from `main.py`; and conversely `main.py` may need variables set in the subscripts. Therefore variables need to be transferred between python-python (`main.py` <--> `sub1.py`) and python-shell (`main.py` <--> `sub2.sh`).

Some ways I know:

- `main.py` --> `sub1.py`: call `sub1.py` from `main.py` via `os.system()` or
  `subprocess.Popen()`, pass variables as script arguments, retrieve from e.g. `sys.argv[1]` in `sub1.py`
- `main.py` --> `sub1.py`: import `sub1.py` into `main.py`; variables from `main.py` must be set to `sub1.py` namespace, else not recognized by `sub1.py`; if there's non-function/-class code in `sub1.py` (i.e. "global" script code, is it executed properly as well)?
- `main.py` --> `sub2.sh`: call `sub2.sh` from `main.py` via
  `os.system()` or `subprocess.Popen()`, pass variables as script
  arguments, retrieve from e.g. `$1` in `sub2.sh`
- all directions / script types: store variables in some file from one script in whichever format (e.g. .txt, .dat, .pickle (for python-python transfer)), read variables from file in the other script
- all directions / script types: store variables as environment variables from one script (in the `os.environ[]` dictionary), extract from there as needed within the other script

**Question: What is the *most convenient* method to transfer variables (share info) between python and python or between python and shell scripts?**

Background of the question: `main.py` is a python translation of a previous shell script `main.sh`. In `main.sh`, any subscript `subX.sh` (there were fewer python scripts at that point) was called via `source subX.sh`, such that variables from `main.sh` and `subX.sh` were always known to the respective other scripts (as `source` runs the subscript in the same shell).

The python version used is `2.7.18` (compatibility reasons; I am not allowed to install a newer interpreter).

Comment: *"I do not have admin rights to install a newer interpreter"* You do not need admin rights to install a newer Python version, though it might not be straight forward.

Comment: You can transport variables to the child process via the environment. To transport information from the child back to the parent, the child could create a file containing the content of the variable, and the parent process could read this file and create the variable based on its content.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `sys.argv` from the sys library. See more at : https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Basically, in main.py if you call the function `python sub1.py arg1 arg2`, in sub1.py you can get these arguments with :

```
from sys import argv
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]
```

Be careful, `sys.argv[0]` is not your first argument !

Comment: I know `sys.argv[]` (see my question), but this cannot be applied to `sub2.sh` being called from `main.py`. Apart from that, I'm not sure whether this is actually the most convenient way to transfer the variables...

Comment: I have seen people create template txt files to pass arguments between several code files if that helps